# GPS data blocked by other tasks in the while loop

Tags: gps, embedded, freertos, rtos, stm32f4

I am trying to parse GPS data while reading pressure sensor, IMU sensor and writing some data to SD card. Since reading pressure sensor, IMU sensor and writing SD card takes some time and GPS don't wait my command to send its data, I lost some GPS data so my parser can not find meaningful message. I use `uart_receive` interrupt to take GPS data and circular buffer to save its data. After I parse it. Since I don't know how much bytes come from GPS, I read one by one. I tried FreeRTOS but it did not work. How can I prevent other tasks to block GPS data. I am using STM32f401cc.

Here is my FreeRTOS task;

```
void StartDefaultTask(void* argument)
{
    IMU_setParameters(&imu, &hi2c1, imu_ADD_LOW, GPIOB, GPIOB,
                      GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_2);
    IMU_init(&imu, &htim3);
    while ((calState.accel != 3 || calState.system != 3 || calState.gyro != 3 || calState.mag != 3) && calibFlg)
    {
        IMU_getCalibrationState(&imu, &calState);
    }

    preSensor_init_default_params(&preSensor.params);
    preSensor.addr = preSensor_I2C_ADDRESS_1;
    preSensor.i2c = &hi2c1;

    preSensor_init(&preSensor, &preSensor.params);

    initSD_CARD(&USERFatFS, USERPath);
    samplePacket(&telemetry);
    controlRecoveryFile(&recoveryFile, "recoveryFile.txt", &telemetry);

    for (;;)
    {
        IMU_getDatas(&imu, &calState, &linearAccel, &IMU, &imuFlg, &offsetFlg, &calibCount);
        preSensor_force_measurement(&preSensor);
        preSensor_read_float(&preSensor, &temperature, &pressure, &humidty);
        preSensor_get_height(pressure, &height);

        telemetry.Altitude_PL = height;
        telemetry.Pressure_PL = pressure;
        telemetry.Temperature = temperature;

        telemetry.YRP[0] = IMU.yaw;
        telemetry.YRP[1] = IMU.roll;
        telemetry.YRP[2] = IMU.pitch;

        if (calibCount % 10 == 0)
        {
            writoToTelemetryDatas(&logFile, "tulparLog.txt", &telemetry, 0);
            if (!writeToRecoveryDatas(&recoveryFile, "recoveryFile.txt", &telemetry))
                connectionFlg = 1;
        }
        osDelay(1);
    }
}

void StartTask02(void* argument)
{
    arrangeCircularBuffer(&gpsCircular, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);
    initGPS(&huart1, &rDATA, &gps);

    for (;;)
    {

        getGPSdata(&huart1, &gpsCircular, &gps, &rDATA);

        osDelay(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: FreeRTOS _will_ work (as will any RTOS) - it is not a FreeRTOS issue, it is an issue with your code - which you have chosen not to exhibit, so it is unlikely we can help.  In any event, if you are buffering the data and not missing interrupts, the task scheduling should not cause you to loose data.  Most likely you have tasks that are not yielding the processor and/or inappropriate priority allocation and too short a buffer.  Also of course it is possible that your circular buffer code is wrong.  There are so many ways this may not work, and it is not possible to tell from your _description_.

Comment: With respect to _"I read one by one."_; if it is NMEA0183 data, then you could place characters in the buffer then give a semaphore when a `'\r'` is buffered.  Then in the GNSS task it can simply wait on the semaphore, and read the entire NMEA sentence in one go - minimising the number of context switches.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Clifford. Since I am newb, I have no idea about semaphore. Actually I find the problem "Race condition". Let me explain when meaningfull NMEA sentence come, it is stored in my circular buffer but in main loop untill code come my parser approximately 80 ms past and my parser have 4 states. My one state takes 30+ loop and think that 30*80 ms and so overflow happens. But now I take GPGGA and GPRMC and in one loop make everything about parsing after I take second packet. (SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH)

Comment: If you can explain what is semaphore how to use it or share some documents, it will be very nice for me.

Comment: that is an entirely different question and should be posted as such.  But to be honest, if you are using FreeRTOS (or any RTOS) and don't know what a semaphore is, it is hardly surprising you are having scheduling issues.  It is a fundamental task synchronisation mechanism.  It is covered in detail in the FreeRTOS documentation and more generally pretty much any RTOS 101.  As I said, without the code, it is hard to advise, but you just added more _description of the code_, and in a comment - you need to edit the question.  SO is not a discussion forum.

Comment: I have shared RTOS tasks. I am using interrupt for taking gps datas. And I can skip calibration part with external interrupt.

Comment: Without knowing what is going in in _all_ the calls within both task loops, and the relative priorities assigned, and even the serial ISR itself, it is not possible to determine if your code is schedulable.  However a task loop with a delay is a rather primitive approach to scheduling, and you would do well to learn how to utilise an RTOS more appropriately.

Comment: Whilst it is true that the GPS sentences are variable length, they are limited to a maximum of 82 characters (including CR+LF), so instead of using a circular buffer, you could use an RTOS message queue, and have the ISR accumulate characters in a buffer until the CR+LF then post the entire sentence to the message queue in one go.  Your task would then block on the queue rather than a delay.  Either way you would do well to use RTOS IPC and synchronisation mechanisms rather than a polled non-blocking home-grown buffer that may or may not be thread safe.

Comment: The ways in which this code could be wron remain numerous since you have not exhibited _all_ the code.  For example `calibCount` and `connectionFlg` are global -  and apart being [ill-advised](https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/), without seeing the declaration and where else they are used and in what context(s), it is not possible to determine whether that is safe/valid.  Your `StartDefaultTask` appears to perform file I/O - that is a non-deterministic and potentially lengthy operation, and should be a lower priority than `StartTask02` most likely.

Comment: Another FreeRTOS specific solution would be to use a [stream buffer](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-stream-buffer-example.html) rather than your home-grown and probably flawed circular buffer.   As I say if you are not using RTOS provided IPC and synchronisation mechanisms to exchange information and control scheduling of tasks, then you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: calibCount toggling a led. It indicates that whether IMU calibration has been made or not. Connection flg indicates that sd card properly mounted.

Comment: Right now I do not use Rtos because I do not know anything about that just I tried. I look at your advices and after that try FreeRtos again.

Comment: My StartDefaultTask loop priority lower than StartTask02.

Comment: But your code has `osDelay()` calls.  How is that going to work if the scheduler is not running?  Also the code has infinite loops, if you are not running a preemptive scheduler, they cannot both be running. Re. your comment in `calibCount` that rather suggests you have other threads running.  This is a holistic design issue; if we cannot see all your code, we cannot give a definitive answer.

Comment: ... if you are truly not using FreeRTOS, remove the tag,  and post plausible code.  The code you posted is clearly intended to be multi-threaded.

Comment: I tried FreeRTOS but after I have not used it properly, I changed my code. Still, I can use FreeRTOS. I can not share my whole code because of the privacy. Besides, I solved problem and I wrote provious comment. Please dont judge me like that. Just I wanted learn about how can I fix freeRtos problem. You helped a lot thanks.

Comment: It is legitimate on SO to answer your own question.  Your solution may be of interest/use to others.  Consider posting an answer.

Comment: You are right. I shared my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to problem.

First of all I do not use FreeRtos at all. I do all the thing in main loop. Problem is "Race Condition". In my GPS data parser, there are 4 states. MSG_ID, Finish, Check, Parse. These four states do not take four loops to find meaningfull message. It depends on message length. It can be at most 103 loop. Besides, In main loop my imu sensor, pressure sensor and SD card module takes approximately 80 ms. As you know, GPS works independent from our code. It does not wait our command to send data. Every 1 second it sends its datas. Now, imagine that your GPS sends datas every 1 seconds and your CircularBuffer has 200 bytes. Your parser begin to parse message. But your parser needs at least 30+ loops to find message. Now, 30*80 = 2400 ms (2.4 s). Untill you find meaningfull data GPS sent 2 more datas and overflow happened. To fix this situation, I write for loop for my GPS parser in the main loop and I send command to GPS for just taking GPGGA and GPRMC datas (for GPS command you can look at [here](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/PMTK_A11.pdf). I use uart_receive_ınterrupt to store data to my circularbuffer. After taking 2 '\n', I stop taking data and wait my parser to parse these datas. At the end I start uart operation taking meaningfull datas. Important thing here is calling parser in a for loop. (it can be 8-16-24 loops depends on your other tasks delay)